# Spyder console shows the part of the axis out of xlim in the console with two subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, console, spyder, subplot

I am using Spyder 4.1.2, installed with anaconda, on Windows 10. Python 3.7.7

Whenever I plot a rows*cols-subplots plot, the figure that appears in the spyder console (the section now dedicated to the display of figures) shows also the parts of the axis that should not be plotted, as it is out of the xlim range.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2)

ax[0].vlines([0.2, .8], ymin=0, ymax=1, color='r', clip_on=True)
ax[1].vlines([0.1, .9], ymin=0, ymax=1, color='b', clip_on=True)

ax[0].set_xlim([0, .7])
ax[1].set_xlim([.4, 1])

plt.savefig('fig')
```

[image: this is the screenshot of the console]
The saved file looks perfect, so it simply seems a Spyder thing.
[image: This is the saved figure]

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem disappears when changing from SVG to PNG in the inline settings in:

> Tools > Preferences > IPython console > Graphics > Inline Backend > Format: PNG.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm strange, looks like you're displaying in the 'Plots' area of the IDE.

Plotting them in a separate window may help.

You can do this with the following :

```
Tools > Preferences > IPython console > Graphics > Backend:Inline
```

Change `Inline` to `Automatic`, then reset the kernel or close and reopen `spyder`.

Might not be the solution you were looking for, but might be a suitable workaround.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I would like to continue plotting in the "Plot" area, and the Inline option was already selected. however i tried modifying some of the settings in Tools > Preferences > IPython console > Graphics > Backend:Inline, and I found some improvements.